# How to set defaultCommand in a p:confirmDialog

Tags: primefaces

I use JSF PrimeFaces 6.1 version

I have confirmDialog for several commandButton looks like

```
        <p:commandButton id="applyButton" icon="icon-interaction-upload-3"
                         styleClass="icon-button edit-panel-apply main-button"
                         rendered="#{Bean.editMode}"
                         onclick="setMainButtonYes(); $('[id$=hiddenApplyButton]').click(); return false;"
                         title="Apply"/>
        <p:commandButton id="hiddenApplyButton"
                         actionListener="#{Bean.save}"
                         style="display: none"
                         onstart="saveScrollPosition();blockUi('blockUI')"
                         oncomplete="unblockUi('blockUI');setScrollPosition();">
            <p:confirm header="Blablabla"
                       message="Apply"
                       icon="ui-icon-alert"/>
        </p:commandButton>

        <p:commandButton id="discardButton" icon="icon-interaction-remove-2"
                         styleClass="icon-button edit-panel-discard" rendered="#{Bean.editMode}"
                         title="Discard"
                         onclick="setMainButtonNo(); $('[id$=hiddenDiscardButton]').click(); return false;"/>
        <p:commandButton id="hiddenDiscardButton"
                         actionListener="#{Bean.discardChanges}"

                         style="display: none"
                         onstart="saveScrollPosition();blockUi('blockUI')"
                         oncomplete="unblockUi('blockUI');setScrollPosition();">
            <p:confirm header="Blablabla"
                       message="Discard"
                       icon="ui-icon-alert"/>
        </p:commandButton> 

<p:confirmDialog id="confirmationDialog" global="true" closeOnEscape="true">
            <p:commandButton id="yes" value="Yes"
                             styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes edit-confim-yes yesButtonUpdate"
                             onstart="saveScrollPosition();" oncomplete="setScrollPosition();"
                             icon="ui-icon-check"/>
            <p:commandButton id="no" value="No"
                             styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no edit-confim-no noButtonUpdate main-button"
                             onstart="saveScrollPosition();" oncomplete="setScrollPosition();"
                             icon="ui-icon-close"/>
        </p:confirmDialog>
```

For Apply button when the dialog opened pressing Enter works right and saves changes, but in second case for discard button i want the Enter button to close the dialog without discarding changes. 
I tried to add defaultCommand tag but it doesnt work. How can i set Enter for "no" commandButton in second case?

P.S.
setMainButtonYes/No() function just add needed class to buttons to paint them.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution as you'd expect, but with the limitations of `confirmDialog` maybe the only option would be to change the order of the buttons so that the first button was the default command:

```
<p:confirmDialog id="confirmationDialog" global="true" closeOnEscape="true">
    <p:commandButton id="no" value="No" />
    <p:commandButton id="yes" value="Yes"/>
</p:confirmDialog>
```